# \setminted and \setmintedinline commands interfere with each other?

Tags: listings, minted, inline

I'm trying to use the package `minted` to generate documents which contain language-agnostic inline code and language-aware block code (listing). Here's a minimal working example:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{minted}

\setmonofont{Courier New}
\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.85, 0.85, 0.85}
\setmintedinline{bgcolor=bg}
\setminted{bgcolor=bg, gobble=9, linenos}

\begin{document}


    This is some code \mintinline{text}{x = 3}.

    \begin{listing}[H]
        \begin{minted}{python}
            def print_hello():
                print("hello")
        \end{minted}
        \caption{test}
        \label{test}
    \end{listing}

    \clearpage
\end{document}
```

The resulting document formats the block code correctly, but the inline code is  not shown. If I comment line 10, the inline code is shown, but my block code is no longer formatted how I'd like for it to be.

I'm compiling with the following command in Powershell with texlive:

```
latexmk -lualatex --shell-escape test.tex
```

The `--shell-escape` is needed for `minted` to work properly.

Does anyone know how I can set an inline format and a code-block format for my entire document? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a bug: `gobble` makes no sense for `\mintinline`. However, you may use `autogobble` instead of guessing the right amount of spaces to remove.

Comment: I might look into that at a later stage. For now hardcoding `gobble` in my individual `\setminted` code blocks seems to work

Comment: I've reported this to `minted`: https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/337

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the issue. It's because I'm using `gobble` in `\setminted` which seems to apply also for `\setmintedinline`. Strange, because in the docs the following is mentioned:

> All settings specified with `\setmintedinline` override those set with `\setminted`. That is, inline settings always have a higher precedence than general settings.